# For Page Object Pattern, when designing the page objects in Selenium, how do you handle multiple modals correctly?

Tags: selenium, design-patterns

Let me further explain.
You have a page where an application lives. However, upon first login, the user is prompted with a welcome screen that loads in the center of the browser. Like a pop-up from the application. This welcome screen is to help the user get familiar with the app. You can move on through the screens by reading the information and clicking the Continue button. After several of these pop-ups, the application will now be available for testing.

So how would I handle this in the Page Object Pattern using Selenium. Should I have a main page that just has functionality to navigate through these modals? Or should the main page return objects that represent each of the individual modals? Or should each modal be a separate page that I interact with?

Basically, I can think of several options:

`ApplicationPage.Modal1.Continue();`

or

`Modal1.Continue();`

`Modal2.Continue();`

or

`ApplicationPage.ContinueThroughModal1();`

or

`ModalPage.Continue1();`

`ModalPage.Continue2();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to look at pages as collection of services. So

> should the main page return objects that represent each of the individual modals?

PageObject helps you to improve the maintenance and reduces code duplication. So you can use it as an interface to a page of your AUT.

> should each modal be a separate page that I interact with?

I would say - yes. If some future change occurs (in any modal), your PageObj will handle it without changing the test itself. Why not introduce a `IModalPopup` with `Continue()` method which will handle the skipping that your tests need. Further more in your `MainPage` class you can keep a `ICollection<IModalPopup> welcomeScreens` and iterate those.

Aiming at a full answer here - there is no need to actually go through this

> welcome screen that loads in the center of the browser.

Once is enough. Every other test can utilize [URL navigation](http://wiki.servicenow.com/?title=Navigating_by_URL#gsc.tab=0) over crawling each middle page. Single test that covers your end-user journey (by clicking required buttons/links) should be sufficient.

Comment: Great idea @ekostadinov. Sounds reasonable to me. Will give this a shot and see what happens. Thanks for taking the time to help with this.